# How to define a module with dependencies that have not yet been defined with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, requirejs, qunit

Suppose I have module A that depends on module B and C, but A is defined first. Is there a way to defer the definition of A until B and C have been defined, and then load A with its dependencies?

Some background: I'm working on a proprietary system that uses DOM insertion points to customize page content and behavior. I can't move where modules B and C are defined as these insertion points are inserted on the server side, and I can't touch that.

I've also written a test suite (using QUnit) that imports what can be thought of as module A in the example above. My testrunner page imports QUnit and module A at the top of the page, and modules B and C are imported farther down.

Normally, I would attempt to insert the module A definition into the DOM after module B and C's module definitions, but the particular page I'm writing tests for is using frames, which I believe is loaded after the scripts in the `head` tag are run. If it's possible to modify the DOM of a frame within the header, that might solve my problem.

I know this question doesn't contain any code, but I figured since the nature of this question is more theoretical, I omitted it.

If I was wrong and you'd like to see my code, please ask!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... yes:

```
require(["B", "C"], function () {
    require(["A"]);
});
```

Provided a sane RequireJS configuration and that nothing else is requiring `"A"` before this code runs, modules `"B"` and `"C"` will be defined before module "A" is.

Example of a sane RequireJS configuration:

```
{
    baseUrl: "./js"
}
```

This tells RequireJS that all modules are in the `./js` subdirectory. The files `A.js`, `B.js`, `C.js` that define modules 'A', 'B', 'C' have to be in the `./js` subdirectory.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "sane RequireJS configuration" looks like?

Comment: I've added an example.